Грамматическая основа предложения (2)
Тебе есть к чему стремиться.
Конкретно интересует слово «есть».

Тебе есть к чему стремиться.
Это односоставное безлично-инфинитивное предложение. Есть к чему стремиться  — набор обязательных структурных элементов: связка + инфинитив в позиции сказуемого и дополнение.
Связка есть выражает время и наклонение, стремиться — инфинитив, к чему — местоимение в роли дополнения.
Сравнить (другие формы): Мне было к чему стремиться. Было бы к чему стремиться.
Теория (стр. 93)
Безлично-инфинитивные предложения, как следует из их названия, сочетают в себе свойства безличных и инфинитивных предложений. В качестве обязательных структурных элементов они включают инфинитив, местоимение и связку в безличной форме (в настоящем времени — нулевую).
Безлично-инфинитивные предложения имеют три основные
формы:

Отрицательную: Нечего читать; Не о чем говорить; Незачем
туда ехать; Не к кому обратиться;

Утвердительную: Есть что читать; Есть о чем поговорить;
Есть зачем ехать; Есть к кому обратиться;

Вопросительную: Что нам было читать?; К кому нам было
обратиться?


